# How to Maintain State in an Oracle ApEx Form

Tags: jquery, cookies, oracle10g, session-state, oracle-apex

I have hit a snag and I'm unsure on what the best way to tackle this issue using Oracle ApEx.

Basically I have a form that is based off Table1 but at the same time, a section/region within this form branches to another page where it then adds details into Table2.

To expand on this with a better example, let's say that I have a table called CUSTOMER which holds personal details of the customer, such as CUST_ID, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, DOB and then I also have another table called PURCHASES with the following columns, PURCHASE_ID, CUST_ID, ITEM, ITEM_DESCR, COST with CUST_ID being a foreign key to CUSTOMERS table.

I now want to create an Oracle Apex form based off the table CUSTOMER but within this same form, prior to the user submitting and committing the form to the database, I also want to allow the user to add all the purchases the customer was buying at the store by a means of some sort. Once the user has entered the customer details together with say 5 purchase records (in some way), all is submitted and committed to the database for both the CUSTOMER and PURCHASES tables.

Is there a way around this or possibly other alternatives around this type of situation?

Comment: To further clarify, when you say "a form based off the table CUSTOMER" do you mean a simple data entry form for creating one customer?

Comment: Yes Tony but on this same form, I would like to have a region of some type to allow the user to enter one or more purchases a customer may have but I want this information always displayed within this region in the customer form and then the user commits/submits once with captures CUSTOMER and PURCHASES tables. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have a look at http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=36342:6 - is this what you want?  The first page is just to show the data created by page 7 (press Create button to go there).  Page 7 is "your" page.  When you have entered a customer and some purchases, press Submit.  You should see the new customer you created; click on their name an the purchases will be shown below.

Comment: If that's what you want then tomorrow I can go through how I did it (I have to go now).

Comment: Hey Tony - really appreciate your help and thanks for the example. Based on your example, I am assuming you have used a Master-Detail setup within ApEx - is this correct? Based on your example, how would I go about editing a purchase record? If you have not used a Master-Detail setup then I would really appreciate what approach you used? Thanks again Tony.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the details.  I didn't use a default master/detail wizard.

Comment: To step back a bit - you are making life difficult for yourself as a beginner by being determined to enter a new customer **and** their purchases in one step.  If you would settle for being able to enter a new customer, commit, and then enter their purchases you would be able to do it "out of the box" with minimal effort.  Is this requirement really so important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of **redirecting** to page 2 to enter the Table 2 info you need to **submit** page 1 and **branch** to page 2.  This will save the session state for page 1.  You don't want the page 1 data updated into Table1 yet, so ensure that the process that performs the insert/update is not invoked by this submit - e.g. make it conditional on the Save button or whatever.

Alternatively, do it all on one page like my example [here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=36342:6).  The page of interest is page 7 which you reach via the Create button.  Page 7 has a kind of master/detail form, but I didn't build it using the Apex wizards - I'm not sure whether you could, but I tend not to use the wizards and built-in form-on-table tools in my work, so I am not sure.

This is what I did for page 7:

1) Created a blank page

2) Added an HTML region "New Customer" and added a text item for Surname and a date item for DOB.

3) Created a report region "Purchases" with the following SQL:

```
select apex_item.text(1,'') item_desc
,      apex_item.text(2,'') cost
from   dual
connect by level <= 5
```

The CONNECT BY clause is a trick to generate 5 dummy rows from DUAL.  The `apex_item` package generates tabular form items - in this case 2 text items for item_desc and cost, with '' as the initial value.

4) Created 2 buttons:
SUBMIT - submits the page
CANCEL - redirects to page 6

5) Created a PL/SQL process to run on submit as follows:

```
declare
  l_cust_id integer;
begin
  -- Insert the new customer
  insert into so_customers (surname, dob)
  values (:p7_surname, :p7_dob)
  returning cust_id into l_cust_id;

  -- Insert the purchases (if data has been entered)
  for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(i) is not null then
      insert into so_purchases (cust_id, item_desc, cost)
      values (l_cust_id, 
              apex_application.g_f01(i),
              apex_application.g_f02(i)
             );
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

I made that process conditional on the SUBMIT button.  The `apex_application` package contains array variables g_f01, g_f02 etc. that correspond to the tabular form columns.

6) Created a branch that goes back to page 6 when SUBMIT is pressed.

If you want functionality that deviates from the "out of the box" behaviour provided by Apex's page and region wizards you have to write more complex code, as you can see.  But pretty much anything you want to do can by done this way.

Comment: Thansk @Tony for your answer. The issue I am stuck with is that I have as yet committed any information on the first page yet as I'm wanting to save/commit the first page once all info has been made available. Can you suggest a different means?

Comment: Ah, I think I see - you are losing the Table1 info?

Comment: Thanks again Tony. I have tried another means by where I am using an iframe from page 1 that references page 2 via a tabular form. Not sure though if it's possible to have the parent page actually perform the submit for page 1 and at the same time also submit to the database, page 2 tabular form data. Would you know how to accomplish this or should I start a new thread? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just put both tables on page 1?  I imagine you could submit page 2 in an iframe using some Javascript, but I don't know the details.  It sounds over the top though.  It is quite common to have a process span more than 1 page - it is often called a "wizard", and is most definitely supported by Apex.

Comment: Tony, not sure how this would work with both tables on the same page as the setup is pretty much a master-detail setup but unfortunately I don't particular like the way Oracle ApEx handles master-details setups. I don't particular like the way I've done but I'm still not sure of another way to do this setup.

Comment: I don't really have a good enough handle on what you are trying to do to suggest anything else at the moment.  Perhaps you could update your question with more details about the requirements?  I'm very sure that what you want to do is neither unusual nor difficult to achieve in Apex, but I may be missing something.

Comment: As requested Tony and hopefully it's clearer now but I have updated my question above. Hopefully you can see with my example what I am trying to achieve. Just keep in mind that I am wanting to commit only at the end once I have entered customer and customer purchase details, which I would like to display to the user on the main form as a report prior to committing the form.

Comment: Tony, that is excellent work and once again, I really appreciate the time and effort you have made to help me. I have used the apex_application approach for checkboxes but I suppose I didn't think of using the apex_item in this way. I will definitely try this approach now as I think it's exactly what I am after. The only thing I'not sure about is, how I can take care of deletes and edits on the PURCHASES table for existing customers? Thanks.

Comment: Further this Tony, what happens if I need more than 5 rows of Purchases records while typing in this information as a User - how can I add additional rows if required? Thanks.

Comment: You'd probably be best off creating a new page for editing existing purchases for a customer - just use a built-in tabular form on PURCHASES for example.  Then add a link "Edit purchases" to the Customers report.

Comment: Adding more rows is also complicated - you'd need to add an "Add Rows" button that submits the page, and then you'd need to store the session state for the tabular form in an APEX_COLLECTION, and base the report on that.  It'll get complex ;-)  See this rather old how-to: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/tabular-form-090805.html#MANUAL

Comment: Tony, what happens if I had another report region off another table that say allowed the customer to also enter in a "Wish List" of products, which was similar to the Purchases region. Could I create something like this: select apex_item.text(3,'') item_desc
,apex_item.text(4,'') cost from   dual connect by level <= 5 where apex_application.g_f03(i) and apex_application.g_f04(i) where used. Now how would I go about accessing the data in this report region to store in my table, would I still use: for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you could, ensuring that you use different array numbers as you just did.  For processing you would use `for i in 1..apex_application.g_f03.count`.  This is one of the benefits of "rolling your own" tabular forms: you are not restricted to one per page as you are with the built-in ones.